# Find specific numbers of frequency in an unsorted array

Tags: pseudocode

I have a question:

I have an unsorted array with n numbers,
I need to find the numbers that appear more than 10% in the array.
Can u please write me a pseudo code with the Time complexity

An example:

```
array A = {12,11,1,3,1,4,4,7,8,9,10}
```

The answer is 1,3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hash Table (Hash Map) to solve this.

Iterate you array,
if the hash table does not contain your element (number)
then add it with a counter set to 1
else increment the counter by 1.
Iterate your hash table and keep every entry where the counter is more than 10% of the size of the array.

Time complexity is the cost of iterating the array (n) plus iterating the hash table (worst case : n) : O(n) = 2n

An other solution would be to sort the array then to iterate it counting each element and keeping the element if the count is more than 10%

Time complexity is the cost of a sort (n*log(n)) plus the cost of iterating the array (n) : O(n) = n + n*log(n)